# overload class new operator when custom CUDA allocator is present using tag-dispatch

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, cuda

have created an STL-style, allocator aware class which I'm trying to use with a custom CUDA allocator. The CUDA allocator works fine for allocating the data storage in unified memory, but in order for the `this` pointer to be accessible on both host and device, I need to make sure that whenever the data is allocated in unified memory, that the class is as well.

To solve this, I thought a simple tag dispatch would be appropriate. If the allocater is a `cudaAllocator`, new should create the class in unified memory, and if not, it should just return the regular new output. Unfortunately I think I'm missing something with how tag-dispatch works. Here's the relevant part of the class:

```
#ifdef __CUDACC__
public:

    using cudaAllocator_tag = std::true_type;
    using hostAllocator_tag = std::false_type;

    void *operator new(size_t len)
    {
        return new(len, std::is_same<Alloc, cudaAllocator<value_type>>());
    }

    void operator delete(void *ptr) 
    {
        return delete(ptr, std::is_same<Alloc, cudaAllocator<value_type>>());
    }

    void *operator new(size_t len, cudaAllocator_tag)
    {
        void *ptr;
        cudaMallocManaged(&ptr, len);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        return ptr;
    }

    void operator delete(void *ptr, cudaAllocator_tag) 
    {
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        cudaFree(ptr);
    }

    void *operator new(size_t len, hostAllocator_tag)
    {
        return ::new(len);
    }

    void operator delete(void *ptr, hostAllocator_tag)
    {
        ::delete(ptr);
    }

#endif // __CUDACC__
```

but the (NVCC) compiler throws up with the following errors:

```
2> error : expected a type specifier
2>  
2>            detected during instantiation of "void *CircularQueue<T, Alloc>::operator new(size_t) [with T=float, Alloc=cudaAllocator<float>]" 
2>  
2>  main.cu(21): here
2>  
2>  
2>  
2> error : no instance of overloaded "operator new" matches the argument list
2>  
2>              argument types are: (unsigned long long, size_t, std::is_same<cudaAllocator<float>, cudaAllocator<float>>)
2>  
2>            detected during instantiation of "void *CircularQueue<T, Alloc>::operator new(size_t) [with T=float, Alloc=cudaAllocator<float>]" 
2>  
2>  main.cu(21): here
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. `new` is missing the identifier of the *object to create*. Assuming your container is called `myContainer` It should be:

   ```
   static void *operator new(size_t len)
   {
       return new myContainer(len, std::is_same<Alloc, cudaAllocator<value_type>>());
   }
   ```
2. The arguments of `operator delete` cannot be overloaded like they can for new. You can get around this by having `delete` invoke a custom `destroy` function, using inline and tag-dispatch to avoid any run-time penalties.

   ```
   static void operator delete(void *ptr) 
   {
       destroy(ptr, std::is_same<Alloc, cudaAllocator<value_type>>());
   }
   ```

   to avoid confusion /infinite recursion, it's probably best to do with with `new` as well.

## Complete Solution:

```
#ifdef __CUDACC__
public:

    using cudaAllocator_tag = std::true_type;
    using hostAllocator_tag = std::false_type;
    using isCudaAllocator   = typename std::is_same<Alloc, cudaAllocator<value_type>>;

    static void *operator new(size_t len)
    {
        return create(len, isCudaAllocator());
    }

    static void operator delete(void *ptr) 
    {
        destroy(ptr, isCudaAllocator());
    }

protected:

    static inline void *create(size_t len, cudaAllocator_tag)
    {
        void *ptr;
        cudaMallocManaged(&ptr, len);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        return ptr;
    }

    static inline void destroy(void *ptr, cudaAllocator_tag)
    {
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        cudaFree(ptr);
    }

    static inline void *create(size_t len, hostAllocator_tag)
    {
        return ::new CircularQueue(len);
    }

    static inline void destroy(void *ptr, hostAllocator_tag)
    {
        ::delete(static_cast<CircularQueue*>(ptr));
    }
#endif // __CUDACC__
```